# No, it is not really "too broad"

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

This question came into my review queue.  It was set up to be closed because a number of us thought it was too-broad a question.

[Is it possible to connect to an mdf file without using a server installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265341/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-an-mdf-file-without-using-a-server-installation)

We can, using programming tools, read and write Microsoft Word files, XLS files without installing Microsoft Office, so why not ask about being able to use SQL Server files without installing the engine!

I feel it is a completely legitimate question. What do we do about illegitimate closing of a good question?

Comment: Nominate it for reopening?

Comment: you edit it to make it less broad, which will send it to the reopen queue... or cast a reopen vote. But IMHO, it is a bit broad...

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. If the answer to "Is it possible to do X" is yes, what would you want in addition to the answer "yes"? or "no"? ask that instead. If it isn't possible they'll still tell you such, otherwise we'll have a useful answer rather than just "yes".

Comment: In my opinion, it is too broad. Technically speaking, the answer is yes if you write your own engine, which is clearly too broad of a topic to answer in a single question. Answering "no" is the sane answer but not the most accurate. So I still think it's too broad.

Comment: I agree with the closers and Mike C; "What are all the ways to do X" is Too Broad of a question to ask here.

Comment: @MikeC, the option to write your own engine exists for XLS files as well.  But there are libraries available from Microsoft, as well as many other vendors that abstract away a lot of that work for us.  This question should be treated the same way.

Comment: @RajMore So it should be closed as a request for a library or other off-site resource?

Comment: @RajMore as Mike is pointing out, requests for libraries are off-topic. It'll be VERY hard to not make it broad or a recommendation (or both :/)

Comment: @Patrice the answer could be "there is no native .Net way.  You'd have to research libraries (which we can't recommend to you)"

Comment: *which we can't recommend to you* We can recommend libraries, the OP just can't ask for external resources.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely too broad. It is on the same level as asking how to execute a `.cs` file without using a compiler, or how to preview an html page without a browser.

This question would do better as a conversation piece than as an actual question on Stack Overflow as the answer is clearly to use the already built technology, and any expansion on that is just going to be recreating said technology in some alternative version.

While implementing a custom compiler for a cs file, or a custom rendering engine for an html file may be an interesting topic, it is most certainly not going to fit well here in the Q&A system that Stack Overflow uses.